# Where can I ask about the use of new features in Java 8?

Tags: discussion, questions

I would like to ask because I haven't found real, practical examples using these features.  Is there an appropriate way and place to ask about these features?

Comment: You wanna ask "do people use the features" or HOW to use the features? I don't see either of these questions being good fits for Stack Overflow

Comment: Maybe in a Java chat room?

Comment: If you find a new feature interesting, read the documentation, try it out, and can't figure out why it's not working the way you thought it would work, that's a fine question (make sure you detail what you read, why you think it would work that way, and what exactly you expected). Just asking "what's a practical use for x feature" probably isn't a good question.